# Вопрос по итераторам Java

Tags: java, циклы, коллекции, итераторы

Объясните мне пожалуйста,почему когда я работаю с итератором и забываю проинициализировать сам итератор, то такой цикл будет продолжаться бесконечно?

```
  //этот работает верно 
  Iterator<Object> iterator2 = set.iterator(); 
  while(iterator.hasNext())
  set2.add(iterator.next());

//а вот этот уже начнет разгонять мой процессор до сверхскоростей и все бестолку
while(set.iterator().hasNext())
    set2.add(set.iterator().next());
```

Comment: потому что каждый вызов .iterator() получает **новый** экземпляр  итератора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set.iterator()` всегда создает *новый* итератор; в первой части вашего кода вы создаете его только один раз:

```
Iterator<Object> iterator2 = set.iterator();
```

и так он в последующем цикле наконец исчерпается, `iterator.hasNext()` возвратит значение `false`и цикл онончится,

но во второй части вы его создаете в *цикле опять и опять*:

```
while(set.iterator().hasNext())
```

и так как он всегда *свежий*, метод `.hasNext()` опять и опять возвращает значение `true` и поэтому цикл опять и опять продолжается - до бесконечности.